# Best platform to publicaly share data

Tags: open-science, databases

I'm in the final stage of my PhD, and want to make my datasets publicly available. This is so that my examiners can re-run my regressions, if they wish; but moreover, I want other scholars to be able to use the datasets I compiled for their own purposes. I spent years putting these together, and see no purpose in keeping it to myself "just because". The information is not sensitive, and is already in the public domain (e.g, government statistical sites), albeit mostly in unprocessed form.

Is there a best practice in this regard - a "GitHub" equivalent for datasets?

Comment: You could use your a personal website. (What's wrong with GitHub?)

Comment: I don't know how commonly used it is, but you can take a look at [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/). You get a DOI, making the dataset easy to cite, and the links are unlikely to break for a long time.

Comment: If you want to publish your result, some journals (e.g. GigaScience) offer publically accessible databases for storing your data. @user2768 Github can't store large files

Comment: [UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php) collect and publish datasets for machine learning.

Comment: I will recommend to have a profile at ResearchGate platform as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm biased, as a long-time IEEE member, but I recommend [IEEE Dataport](https://ieee-dataport.org/) as a good place to store large data sets that are likely to be of interest to others.

As their [About page says](https://ieee-dataport.org/about-ieee-dataport):

> IEEE DataPort™ is a universally accessible web-based portal that serves four primary purposes:
>
> 1. Enable individuals and institutions to indefinitely store and make datasets easily accessible to a broad set of researchers, engineers and industry;
> 2. Enable researchers, engineers and industry to gain access to datasets that can be analyzed to advance technology;
> 3. Facilitate data analysis by enabling access to data in the AWS Cloud and by enabling the downloading of datasets
> 4. Supports reproducible research.

Comment: IEEE was *exactly* what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @RandomForestRanger You're welcome!  I'm surprised more people don't know about it, and I'm happy to do my bit to spread the word.